# Newish Windows 10 installation taking ~ 20 minutes in the pre session init phase

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, performance

I installed Windows 10 on my Dell Precision T5400 a little over a week ago. It is a pretty old computer but it has two physical 4 core xeon processors, 32GB of Ram and a Crucial 525GB SSD. It is very speedy once it gets booted up and I have been using it for doing video editing and playing around with the new linux subsystem built in. The lengthy boot time is very inconvenient though. When installing it took forever to boot and each subsequent time has taken forever to boot. I actually thought it was just installing updates the first few times. I recently started trying to diagnose and repair the problem and I have only been able to narrow the excessive boot time down to the pre session init phase. I would also note that it takes just as long to do a safe mode boot without networking. I downloaded and installed the performance recorder tools but beyond seeing that it is something in the pre session init phase I am at loss as to what to do next. If someone could help steer me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate. I am unsure how to post the logs in this post but I will be glad to with some instruction. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 on MBR or GPT?

Comment: I believe I installed it to MBR. This is my first Windows 10 fresh install but I installed as I normally would have done Windows 7 on a new drive. Do you know how I can tell for sure?

Comment: In order for me to submit an accurate answer.  You need to be 100% sure your using MBR instead of GPT.  You also need to check if your hardware supports UEFI mode, because my advice, involves switching from MBR to GPT.

Comment: share the generated ETL file (compressed as zip) and I'll analyze it

Comment: I am for sure booting MBR but it looks like my bios does not support UEFI. I am about to upload my zipped ETL if I can.

Comment: I am not sure this is the proper way to share but here is a link to the file on dropbox. If there is a better way let me know and I will reshare. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cikxa6galokijkk/Trace.04-27-2017.08-39-12.Boot_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: I got the file ad posted an answer from what I saw in the trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see why Windows boots slowly you need to install the Windows Performance Toolkit, which is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

[image]
<sup>(all other entries can be unselected)</sup>

Run **WPRUI.exe**, select **First Level**, **CPU Usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. Number of iteration can be set to **1** and click to **start**.

[image]

This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0.

Now make a double click on the generated ETL file to open the ETL in `Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA.exe)`, click on `Profiles`->`Apply`->`Browse Catalog` and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile` you see this overview:

Here indeed the `Boot-PreSessionInit-Phase` is very slow.

[image]

To see what is slow here we need to do a 2nd step. Open cmd.exe in the current folder of your ETL and run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\xperf.exe" /tti /tle -i Trace.04-27-2017.08-39-12.Boot_1.etl -o summary_boot.xml -a boot`.

Open the `summary_boot.xml` and here you also see that `PreSMSS` is slow.

[image]

> What Happens in This Subphase The **PreSMSS subphase** begins when the
>   kernel is invoked. During this subphase, the kernel initializes data
>   structures and components. It also starts the **PnP manager, which
>   initializes the BOOT_START drivers that were loaded during the
>   OSLoader phase. When the PnP manager detects a device, it loads and
>   initializes the device’s drivers**
>
> Visual Cues PreSMSS begins approximately when the “Loading Windows”
>   splash screen appears. There are no explicit visual cues for the end
>   of PreSMSS.

So loading a driver for a device is the cause of the slow boot. But I only see ACPI system, not the real driver.

In WPA, I see a [high CPU usage for SYSTEM process](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis), when looking at `CPU Usage (Sampling) graph`:

[image]

This also shows starting device causes high CPU usage and ACPI calls.

Now we drag & drop the [CPU Usage (precise) graph to analysis pane and analyze the waits](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis).

[image]

Here I can see the start call `ntoskrnl.exe!IopInitializeBootDrivers` and next `ataport.SYS!FdoPowerUpDevice`. So Windows tries to start an ATA/IDE device. Looking at your system Hardware I see you use a DVD drive `PLDS DVD+-RW DH-16A6S`. Is this the IDE drive? If yes, try to disconnect it and look if boot is faster.

Comment: Thats it! Boot time went from 20 minutes to less than 1 minute! I have another DVD drive I can swap out and I am also thinking maybe if that doesnt help I could switch to another sata port. Either way I am happy to mark this as answered, as you have definitely found the source, and helped me understand how to read the ETL file better. Thank you!

Comment: nice to hear that it fixed it. Read [here how to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Swapping the dvd drive did not help. I am going to change the cable and the port it is plugged into next.

Comment: Just an FYI: I changed the cable and moved the drive from sata-2 to sata-4 and my boot time is at < 1 min again. Not sure which one was the fix but I am tired of changing things and waiting 20 minutes.

Comment: ok, nice to hear that it is fixed now :)

Comment: Hi, my Windows 10 is with this slowness problem too. I created a question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1469370/more-than-1-minute-to-boot-windows-10-even-with-ssd. 
Could anyone help?

Comment: @RogérioDec I posted a hint after a short look at the trace.