# Why is "FileSystemControl" causing long boot times?

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-domain

I have a notebook running Windows 7 joined to a Win2008 Domain.

When the notebook is connected to the domain network, it boots up in less than 60 seconds. But when it's disconnected from the network (NICs disabled), it can take 5-10 minutes just to get to the login prompt. Logging in takes only a few seconds whether on or off the domain network, but bootup time is significantly affected.

To diagnose this issue, I ran Process Monitor and had it do boot-time logging. The culprit seems to be a "FileSystemControl" operation taking place in the svchost process:

[image]

You can see that test resulted in over 5 minutes spent on that process.

Here's more info from procmon on that particular instance of svchost:

```
Description:    Host Process for Windows Services
Company:    Microsoft Corporation
Name:   svchost.exe
Version:    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Path:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
Command Line:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted
PID:    480
Parent PID: 792
Session ID: 0
User:   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Auth ID:    00000000:000003e7
Architecture:   64-bit
Virtualized:    False
Integrity:  System
Started:    10/12/2017 10:48:39 AM
Ended:  (Running)

Modules:

user32.dll  0x76de0000  0xfa000 C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    11/10/2016 12:33:04 PM
kernel32.dll    0x76ee0000  0x11f000    C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    10/11/2016 11:34:45 AM
ntdll.dll   0x77000000  0x1aa000    C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   10/11/2016 11:33:37 AM
svchost.exe 0xff140000  0xb000  C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 1:44:07 PM
netcfgx.dll 0x7fef9d80000   0x84000 C:\Windows\System32\netcfgx.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:00:42 PM
msxml6.dll  0x7fefa6c0000   0x1f1000    C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.30.7601.23403 3/25/2016 3:00:58 PM
WinSCard.dll    0x7fefa8c0000   0x39000 C:\Windows\System32\WinSCard.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:05:03 PM
wlanutil.dll    0x7fefa900000   0x7000  C:\Windows\System32\wlanutil.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:35:22 PM
l2gpstore.dll   0x7fefa910000   0x15000 C:\Windows\System32\l2gpstore.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:59:04 PM
wlgpclnt.dll    0x7fefa930000   0x1f000 C:\Windows\System32\wlgpclnt.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:35:26 PM
eappcfg.dll 0x7fefa950000   0x44000 C:\Windows\System32\eappcfg.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 2:57:49 PM
eappprxy.dll    0x7fefa9a0000   0x14000 C:\Windows\System32\eappprxy.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:57:52 PM
onex.dll    0x7fefa9c0000   0x40000 C:\Windows\System32\onex.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   11/20/2010 9:12:24 AM
wlansec.dll 0x7fefaa00000   0x7d000 C:\Windows\System32\wlansec.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:05:34 PM
wlanmsm.dll 0x7fefaa80000   0x6a000 C:\Windows\System32\wlanmsm.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:05:32 PM
dhcpcsvc.dll    0x7fefab30000   0x18000 C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:57:13 PM
wlansvc.dll 0x7fefab50000   0xdd000 C:\Windows\System32\wlansvc.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:05:35 PM
winnsi.dll  0x7fefae00000   0xb000  C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:04:56 PM
IPHLPAPI.DLL    0x7fefae10000   0x27000 C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 2:59:05 PM
uxsms.dll   0x7fefb1b0000   0x10000 C:\Windows\System32\uxsms.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:04:24 PM
comctl32.dll    0x7fefb1c0000   0x1f4000    C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.23403_none_e36ad4593102f066\comctl32.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.10 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) 3/25/2016 2:55:01 PM
wtsapi32.dll    0x7fefb3c0000   0x11000 C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:34:20 PM
mstask.dll  0x7fefb4a0000   0x3d000 C:\Windows\System32\mstask.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   11/20/2010 9:07:51 AM
taskschd.dll    0x7fefb4e0000   0x127000    C:\Windows\System32\taskschd.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:04:00 PM
dsrole.dll  0x7fefb660000   0xc000  C:\Windows\System32\dsrole.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:27:57 PM
PeerDist.dll    0x7fefb690000   0x30000 C:\Windows\System32\PeerDist.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:32:20 PM
cscsvc.dll  0x7fefb7b0000   0xad000 C:\Windows\System32\cscsvc.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:59:51 PM
avrt.dll    0x7fefb9c0000   0x9000  C:\Windows\System32\avrt.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:25:42 PM
propsys.dll 0x7fefb9d0000   0x12c000    C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll Microsoft Corporation   7.00.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)   3/25/2016 3:02:16 PM
MMDevAPI.dll    0x7fefbb40000   0x4b000 C:\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:29:12 PM
powrprof.dll    0x7fefbb90000   0x2c000 C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:03:06 PM
audiosrv.dll    0x7fefbbc0000   0xac000 C:\Windows\System32\audiosrv.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   6/14/2016 1:16:37 PM
pcwum.dll   0x7fefbfa0000   0xd000  C:\Windows\System32\pcwum.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:32:16 PM
gpapi.dll   0x7fefbfe0000   0x1b000 C:\Windows\System32\gpapi.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23452 (win7sp1_ldr.160512-0600)    5/12/2016 1:14:54 PM
devrtl.dll  0x7fefc000000   0x12000 C:\Windows\System32\devrtl.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:56:36 PM
credssp.dll 0x7fefc0f0000   0xa000  C:\Windows\System32\credssp.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23642 (win7sp1_ldr.170105-0730)    1/5/2017 2:56:06 PM
rsaenh.dll  0x7fefc210000   0x47000 C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:32:41 PM
cryptsp.dll 0x7fefc510000   0x18000 C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23471 (win7sp1_ldr.160614-0600)    6/14/2016 1:20:25 PM
kerberos.dll    0x7fefc530000   0xb8000 C:\Windows\System32\kerberos.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   1/5/2017 2:55:07 PM
bcrypt.dll  0x7fefc660000   0x22000 C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23642 (win7sp1_ldr.170105-0730)    1/5/2017 2:52:20 PM
authz.dll   0x7fefc6e0000   0x2f000 C:\Windows\System32\authz.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:25:28 PM
cryptdll.dll    0x7fefc790000   0x14000 C:\Windows\System32\cryptdll.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:59:39 PM
secur32.dll 0x7fefcaa0000   0xb000  C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23642 (win7sp1_ldr.170105-0730)    1/5/2017 2:53:22 PM
sysntfy.dll 0x7fefcaf0000   0xa000  C:\Windows\System32\sysntfy.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:33:52 PM
sspicli.dll 0x7fefcb00000   0x25000 C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23642 (win7sp1_ldr.170105-0730)    1/5/2017 2:53:22 PM
cryptbase.dll   0x7fefcb90000   0xf000  C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23642 (win7sp1_ldr.170105-0730)    1/5/2017 2:56:10 PM
winsta.dll  0x7fefcc40000   0x3d000 C:\Windows\System32\winsta.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:05:14 PM
RpcRtRemote.dll 0x7fefcc80000   0x14000 C:\Windows\System32\RpcRtRemote.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    11/20/2010 9:13:19 AM
profapi.dll 0x7fefcd30000   0xf000  C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   7/13/2009 9:32:15 PM
msasn1.dll  0x7fefcd40000   0xf000  C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:00:37 PM
userenv.dll 0x7fefcd50000   0x1f000 C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:04:17 PM
devobj.dll  0x7fefcd70000   0x1a000 C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:56:35 PM
KernelBase.dll  0x7fefcd90000   0x6a000 C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    10/11/2016 11:34:46 AM
cfgmgr32.dll    0x7fefcec0000   0x36000 C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:55:52 PM
wintrust.dll    0x7fefcf20000   0x3b000 C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23566 (win7sp1_ldr.161004-0600)    10/4/2016 11:32:42 AM
crypt32.dll 0x7fefcf60000   0x16d000    C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23566 (win7sp1_ldr.161004-0600)    10/4/2016 11:35:07 AM
shlwapi.dll 0x7fefd0f0000   0x71000 C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:03:19 PM
msvcrt.dll  0x7fefd450000   0x9f000 C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll  Microsoft Corporation   7.0.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:00:48 PM
gdi32.dll   0x7fefd4f0000   0x67000 C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23591 (win7sp1_ldr.161106-0500)    11/6/2016 12:33:28 PM
lpk.dll 0x7fefd6f0000   0xe000  C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23587 (win7sp1_ldr.161102-0600)    11/2/2016 11:32:33 AM
setupapi.dll    0x7fefd700000   0x1d7000    C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:03:11 PM
rpcrt4.dll  0x7fefd8e0000   0x12d000    C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   1/5/2017 2:52:35 PM
sechost.dll 0x7fefda10000   0x1f000 C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:03:24 PM
ws2_32.dll  0x7fefda30000   0x4d000 C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll  Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   5/11/2016 1:02:51 PM
shell32.dll 0x7fefda80000   0xd8c000    C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:03:14 PM
oleaut32.dll    0x7fefe830000   0xda000 C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23569  10/7/2016 11:32:52 AM
usp10.dll   0x7fefe910000   0xca000 C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll   Microsoft Corporation   1.0626.7601.23585 (win7sp1_ldr.161027-0600) 10/27/2016 11:33:58 AM
clbcatq.dll 0x7fefecb0000   0x99000 C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll Microsoft Corporation   2001.12.8531.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:56:08 PM
nsi.dll 0x7fefed50000   0x8000  C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 3:01:49 PM
advapi32.dll    0x7fefed60000   0xdb000 C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23572 (win7sp1_ldr.161011-0600)    10/11/2016 11:32:00 AM
msctf.dll   0x7fefee40000   0x109000    C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   10/11/2016 11:33:06 AM
imm32.dll   0x7fefef50000   0x2e000 C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23403 (win7sp1_ldr.160325-0600)    3/25/2016 2:58:42 PM
ole32.dll   0x7fefef80000   0x203000    C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll   Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   3/25/2016 3:01:56 PM

Stack:

0   fltmgr.sys  fltmgr.sys + 0x20f7 0xfffff88000c770f7  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
1   fltmgr.sys  fltmgr.sys + 0x2fc7 0xfffff88000c77fc7  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
2   fltmgr.sys  fltmgr.sys + 0x20942    0xfffff88000c95942  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
3   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe + 0x37f57a 0xfffff80002f9857a  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
4   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe + 0x3937fa 0xfffff80002fac7fa  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
5   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe + 0x34cf42 0xfffff80002f65f42  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
6   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe + 0x6f693  0xfffff80002c88693  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
7   ntdll.dll   ntdll.dll + 0x4c0ca 0x7704c0ca  C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
8   cscsvc.dll  cscsvc.dll + 0x1f3b 0x7fefb7b1f3b   C:\Windows\System32\cscsvc.dll
9   cscsvc.dll  cscsvc.dll + 0x6f67 0x7fefb7b6f67   C:\Windows\System32\cscsvc.dll
10  kernel32.dll    kernel32.dll + 0x159cd  0x76ef59cd  C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
11  ntdll.dll   ntdll.dll + 0x2a561 0x7702a561  C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
```

What can I do to investigate this further and resolve it? "FileSystemControl" doesn't tell me a whole lot about what is causing the long boot times.

Comment: from the PID, can you determine which services are loaded into that svchost instance? I usually use `tasklist /SVC` and look for the PID in question.

Comment: I added the info from that particular instance of svchost, with a list of all the loaded modules. No way for me to tell which ones are problematic, though.

Comment: apparently Superfetch, OfflineFiles, and the Storage service run out of that svchost instance (LocalSystemNetworkRestricted), so you have lots of potential culprits.  what happens if you disable offline files and Superfetch?

Comment: [try WPT](https://superuser.com/a/1205327/174557) use the [SDK for Build 10586](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771) which is last version that works with Windows 7. Newer WPT Build require at least Windows 8.

Comment: I have found that such long run times are usually caused by network time-outs. You could try disabling WiFi (or enabling "airplane mode") during boot-up. You can re-enable when you get the log-on prompt.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'll give that a try and if no change use WPT as magicandre1981 suggested

Comment: @AFH No change when network adapters are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was two settings that were buried in a GPO that someone else created:

[image]

The value for "Specify startup policy processing wait time" was set to 5 minutes, and the "Always wait for the network at computer startup" was enabled, causing the long boot times.

Comment: Note that "someone else" could be the domain administrator, the next time that you join the domain check if that settings get reset to the previous values (maybe you have to change that values again after disconnecting from the domain).

Comment: how did you find this? via trial & error?

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez or I'll just remove the GPO since I'm the network admin ;)

Comment: @magicandre1981 RSoP tool and going through each GPO that has computer settings applied. This one immediately caught my eye.

Comment: @Moses Yes, that helps a lot :-)