# Windows 10 boots for more than 10 minutes even after a reset

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd

My Windows 10 PC (which i hardly used since purchasing a laptop) was full of unused stuff, both SSD and regular hard drive had really low amount of free storage and it took really abnormal long time to boot.

I'm talking about the black boot screen with blue Windows logo and rotating dots circle animation.

I guessed it's because a lot of bloatware and low free space so i just used the built in "Reset this PC" option.

Even after resetting it and deleting all the files and settings it now takes the same time to boot.

Any idea what causes it? 
Since resetting it didn't help it must be Hardware right?
My guess is something in the SSD drive, which contains the Windows installation, but i'm not sure on how to check it.

Comment: [analyze boot with WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1205327/174557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command line “***chkdsk /r /f***” to have a basic check/repair on disk. Also, you can contact the hardware provider/manufacturer/supporter and they may help you to do a specific hardware health detection.

Also, below suggestion can be considered as a reference.

Running System Maintenance troubleshooter:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\System and Security

Update hardware drivers, including NIC, Graphic, BIOS, Firmware. You can using system built-in Windows Update to check/install latest hardware driver, also, you can manually access hardware manuafacturer’s website to check/download appropriate drivers.

**How to: Install and Update Hardware Drivers in Windows 10:**
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/how-to-install-and-update-hardware-drivers-in/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293

Disable startup time which has high startup impact:
Task Manager\Startup\select the item and click Disable

Disable/enable fast boot and re-start system to check the result:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Choose what the power buttons do\ tick or untick Turn on fast startup (recommended)\Save Changes