# After upgrade to WIndows 10 version 2004 boot time has increased by more than 3 minutes

Tags: windows-10, boot, upgrade, delayed-execution

I have HP Pavilion 300-010in Mini Desktop PC. It came loaded with Windows 8. Upgraded to Windows 10. Was working very well till Windows 10 version 1909. After upgrade to Windows 10 version 2004 boot time has increased by more than 3 minutes. Due to the screen which stays for about 3 minutes after login screen before the desktop appears. Which says "just a moment" as shown below. Already tried everything I found on net [including this](https://superuser.com/questions/1267092/windows-10-boots-for-more-than-10-minutes-even-after-a-reset). Need Help.

***This screenshot was taken from other PC on VNC.***

[image]

Comment: Is the machine on a domain?

Comment: It is on a home network.

Comment: Does it persist after a reboot?

Comment: Can you clarify what version you are running?  There is not any V2005 that I know of. Are you running Windows Insider?  That takes a couple of minutes to boot on a hard drive. I think Microsoft is continuing to polish the Insider version.

Comment: @spikey_fichie Yes it persists after many reboots.

Comment: @John sorry I meant 2004 andi it is not Windows Insider.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/how-to-fix-windows-10-slow-boot-after-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Since I need to show you a picture I am placing this as answer not a comment.

You need to find out what its doing via process monitor.  Right clicking next to the detail column heading should result in select columns shown here.

[image]

Then we need to select **Duration**.
[image: Duration]

[image]

[image]

Click OK.

Now you have to reboot.

Wait until your at the desktop and you need to relaunch.

It will then ask you to save the file, do so.

Go under File and turn **capture events** off.

Now your going to have a log containing 100,000's of entries possibly into the millions.

Unfortunately your going to have to sift through this mess.

First thing to do is sort by duration and see if its a single thing slowing the whole system down.

There are a few built-in tools you can try using.  Under tools there's a file summary and you can sort this by **file time**.  These numbers are in seconds so you might be able to identify the culprit here.

Sadly your going to have to save this as a CSV file and load it into MS EXCEL or libreoffice calc so you can sort by duration.