# Win 10 Very Slow Boot - Pre Session Init Process Lasts 8 Minutes

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

My HP Laptop usually boots in less than 2 minutes.  Lately is it taking between 8 to 10 minutes to boot. I have already updated the BIOS and all the latest drivers I could find.  I ran the Microsoft performance analyzer and I can clearly see the system hangs on the very first process, Pre Session Init.  The CPU goes to 100% and this lasts for about 8 minutes.  Once it gets past this process, all drivers and programs load in less than a minute and I get a sign on screen.

I also ran The HP built in UEFI hardware diagnostics on every hardware components pass all the tests.

System Specs:

> Win 10 Pro
>   Intel i7-7700HQ 2.8GHz
>   16GB Samsung 2400 RAM
>   NVidia GTX 150
>   Intel HD Graphics 630
>   Realtek H Audio
>   latest Bios / Drivers. Windows Updates

MS Analyzer Screen Shot:

[image: Click Here for MS Analyzer Screen Shot]

[Here is an image of what you requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDudA.png)

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1205327/174557 look in generic event graüph which operation takes so long. if you need help, share the ETL file

Comment: I just added an image that shows the kernel is trying to access a drive.  I think. How do i figure out which drive that is?

Comment: share the ETL so that I can analyze it for you.

Comment: Magic, I really appreciate your help on this. I have bee reading that the ETL files contain personally identifying and security information.  Is it safe to post it on an open bulletin board?

Comment: I only see the name, but no content of the files. I've created a [file request in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/request/ztLXd2PdiljFgI13Gq1h) where you can upload the zipped ETL (to reduce file size to up- and download). Here I only see the files.

Comment: any update? I can't see any uploads in my dropbox