# Windows 10 boot slow Pre Session Init 40 seconds Aggressive LPM

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, performance

I had an issue where pc starts to boot than pauses for 40 seconds while Windows logo and dots are spinning, no harddrive activity and keyboard and mouse are powered off, after 41 seconds boot proceeds as normal. I [used Windows Performance Analyser as per this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1205024/newish-windows-10-installation-taking-20-minutes-in-the-pre-session-init-phase).

Investigation in Windows Performance Analyser shows Pre Session Init taking 41 seconds mostly doing idling.

[image: boot timeline]

Some process activity was detected at ntoskrnl.exe and ACPI.sys which led me to believe driver initialisation issues.

Comment: Are you asking a question or just publishing information?  If you’re asking a question, please [edit] your post to make it clearer and more complete. Otherwise, break this up into a question and an answer; edit the question to be ***only*** the question, and then post an answer below it.

Comment: only ask the question (not both into 1 post) and add your findings into an answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, splitting post into question and answer. Hope this would help someone trying to fit old hardware into new a motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Various attempts to disconnect devices from motherboard pointed at DVD drive, diconnecting it reduced Pre Session Init from 40 to 10 seconds. Next, I attempted to tweak BIOS settings for SATA controller, particularly Aggressive Link Power Management, when it is off then there was no delays in boot. I hope this research would help someone.