# Windows Boot PreSessionInit time up to 140sec Struggling to find reason

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, performance

Windows Boot PreSessionInit time up to 140sec. Struggling to find reason.

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
OS Version:                6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9 GenuineInt
el ~2101 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Insyde Corp. R0093C6, 8/22/2012
Available Physical Memory: 1,296 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  21,478 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 9,341 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    12,137 MB
```

followed this guide: [Newish Windows 10 installation taking ~ 20 minutes in the pre session init phase](https://superuser.com/questions/1205024/newish-windows-10-installation-taking-20-minutes-in-the-pre-session-init-phase/1205327#1205327)

what I found is:

```
interval endTime="130463" startTime="0" name="PreSMSS" duration="130463"
```

however I could not find any driver that cause such a lag.

etl link: 
https://mega.nz/#!pmpByQ6D!SouVWRGd3tJQfLMO3XMmiJJBFf3OG5CrMKOqzmPP5-I

it seems like smth loops/waits after bootstart and before systemstart, but it lacks an information what exactly. (I don`t know how to profile it or find here in logs)

(any advise or a link for a tutorial will be much appreciated. Thanks.)

```
-<pnp>


-<phase endTime="811" startTime="59" name="bootStart" duration="752">

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="504" startTime="370" name="\Driver\kl1" duration="134" prePendTime="134" activity="Init"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="192" startTime="119" name="ACPI\PNP0A08\0" duration="74" prePendTime="74" activity="Enum" friendlyName="" description="PCI Express Root Complex"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="565" startTime="522" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_282A+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_04\3+11583659+0+FA" duration="43" prePendTime="43" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) Mobile Express Chipset SATA RAID Controller"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="319" startTime="291" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E16+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_C4\3+11583659+0+E3" duration="29" prePendTime="29" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 - 1E16"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="257" startTime="228" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E10+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_C4\3+11583659+0+E0" duration="29" prePendTime="29" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 - 1E10"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="351" startTime="323" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E1C+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_C4\3+11583659+0+E6" duration="28" prePendTime="28" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 - 1E1C"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="288" startTime="262" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E12+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_C4\3+11583659+0+E1" duration="27" prePendTime="27" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 - 1E12"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="96" startTime="73" name="ACPI_HAL\PNP0C08\0" duration="23" prePendTime="23" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System"/>

</phase>


-<phase endTime="130452" startTime="130159" name="systemStart" duration="293">

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130258" startTime="130190" name="KLIF" duration="67" prePendTime="67" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="130258" startTime="130206" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\KLIF" duration="52" prePendTime="52" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130316" startTime="130273" name="BasicRender" duration="43" prePendTime="43" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="130316" startTime="130277" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\BasicRender" duration="39" prePendTime="39" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130316" startTime="130277" name="dlkmd" duration="39" prePendTime="39" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130316" startTime="130277" name="DXGKrnl" duration="39" prePendTime="39" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="130316" startTime="130282" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\DLKMD" duration="33" prePendTime="33" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130316" startTime="130283" name="DXGKrnl" duration="33" prePendTime="33" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130452" startTime="130438" name="ahcache" duration="14" prePendTime="14" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130173" startTime="130160" name="klhk" duration="13" prePendTime="13" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130190" startTime="130180" name="klbackupflt" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="130452" startTime="130442" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\ahcache" duration="10" prePendTime="10" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130337" startTime="130327" name="tdx" duration="10" prePendTime="10" activity="Load"/>

</phase>


-<phase endTime="-1" startTime="130452" name="remainder" duration="-1">

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="134089" startTime="132745" name="PCI\VEN_10EC+DEV_5209+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_01\4+2baf440c+0+00E1" duration="1344" prePendTime="1344" activity="Enum" friendlyName="" description="Realtek PCIE CardReader"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132672" startTime="132268" name="ACPI\SNYA006\4+9952f73+0" duration="404" prePendTime="0" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Synaptics SMBus ClickPad"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="131315" startTime="130940" name="i8042prt" duration="375" prePendTime="375" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="134729" startTime="134415" name="USB\VID_2109+PID_2813\5+c173ee4+0+2" duration="314" prePendTime="314" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Generic USB Hub"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="135393" startTime="135088" name="USB\VID_8087+PID_0024\5+27e71cae+0+1" duration="305" prePendTime="305" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Generic USB Hub"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="135088" startTime="134783" name="USB\VID_8087+PID_0024\5+17ed8b27+0+1" duration="305" prePendTime="305" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Generic USB Hub"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="136300" startTime="135997" name="USB\VID_05E3+PID_0608\7+18170aa1+0+3" duration="304" prePendTime="304" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Generic USB Hub"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="135713" startTime="135411" name="USB\VID_1A40+PID_0201\6+2df9aaad+0+1" duration="302" prePendTime="302" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Generic USB Hub"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="131623" startTime="131332" name="SynTP" duration="292" prePendTime="292" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="131623" startTime="131359" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\SynTP" duration="265" prePendTime="265" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130853" startTime="130606" name="vwifibus" duration="246" prePendTime="246" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="135968" startTime="135725" name="USB\VID_08FF+PID_168F\6+28e163e5+0+1" duration="244" prePendTime="244" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="AuthenTec Inc. AES1660"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="134359" startTime="134206" name="HDAUDIO\FUNC_01+VEN_10EC+DEV_0275+SUBSYS_104D6600+REV_1000\4+3b6b84d4+0+0001" duration="152" prePendTime="0" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Realtek High Definition Audio"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132280" startTime="132143" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E20+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_04\3+11583659+0+D8" duration="138" prePendTime="0" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="High Definition Audio Controller"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132254" startTime="132143" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_088E+SUBSYS_40608086+REV_24\4+1c17e3ac+0+00E0" duration="111" prePendTime="29" activity="Start" friendlyName="Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235" description="Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="134198" startTime="134093" name="USB\ROOT_HUB30\4+5999dd8+0+0" duration="105" prePendTime="105" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="USB Root Hub (xHCI)"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132264" startTime="132172" name="PCI\VEN_10EC+DEV_5209+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_01\4+2baf440c+0+00E1" duration="92" prePendTime="0" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Realtek PCIE CardReader"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132247" startTime="132172" name="PCI\VEN_10EC+DEV_8168+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_07\4+2519d1f+0+00E3" duration="75" prePendTime="33" activity="Start" friendlyName="Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller" description="Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="141245" startTime="141179" name="luafv" duration="66" prePendTime="66" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="144862" startTime="144797" name="hcmon" duration="65" prePendTime="65" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="144862" startTime="144800" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\hcmon" duration="62" prePendTime="62" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="146882" startTime="146820" name="USB\ROOT_HUB20\4+18c659bc+0" duration="62" prePendTime="62" activity="Enum" friendlyName="" description="USB Root Hub"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="141245" startTime="141184" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\luafv" duration="62" prePendTime="62" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132265" startTime="132205" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E26+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_04\3+11583659+0+E8" duration="60" prePendTime="60" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E26"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132095" startTime="132046" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E31+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_04\3+11583659+0+A0" duration="50" prePendTime="0" activity="Start" friendlyName="Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 0100 (Microsoft)" description="USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132128" startTime="132083" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E2D+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_04\3+11583659+0+D0" duration="45" prePendTime="45" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E2D"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="132732" startTime="132689" name="IntcAzAudAddService" duration="43" prePendTime="43" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132046" startTime="132004" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_0166+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_09\3+11583659+0+10" duration="42" prePendTime="42" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132083" startTime="132046" name="PCI\VEN_8086+DEV_1E3A+SUBSYS_90A5104D+REV_04\3+11583659+0+B0" duration="37" prePendTime="37" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) Management Engine Interface "/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="146820" startTime="146784" name="USB\VID_05CA+PID_18C6\6+28e163e5+0+3" duration="36" prePendTime="36" activity="Enum" friendlyName="" description="USB Composite Device"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130620" startTime="130584" name="fastfat" duration="36" prePendTime="36" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="144987" startTime="144953" name="IntelHaxm" duration="34" prePendTime="34" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="132311" startTime="132280" name="ACPI\GenuineIntel_-_Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_-_______Intel(R)_Core(TM)_i7-3612QM_CPU_@_2.10GHz\_7" duration="31" prePendTime="31" activity="Start" friendlyName="Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz" description="Intel Processor"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="136363" startTime="136334" name="BTHUSB" duration="29" prePendTime="29" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="unknown" endTime="144987" startTime="144958" name="\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\IntelHaxm" duration="29" prePendTime="29" activity="unknown"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130606" startTime="130578" name="NETwNe64" duration="29" prePendTime="29" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130528" startTime="130501" name="igfx" duration="27" prePendTime="27" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="134391" startTime="134367" name="SCSI\Disk+Ven_Seagate+Prod_Expansion\000000" duration="24" prePendTime="24" activity="Start" friendlyName="Seagate Expansion SCSI Disk Device" description="Disk drive"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="131683" startTime="131660" name="mshidkmdf" duration="23" prePendTime="23" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130892" startTime="130870" name="RTL8168" duration="22" prePendTime="22" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="142909" startTime="142887" name="HTTP" duration="21" prePendTime="21" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130924" startTime="130904" name="CmBatt" duration="21" prePendTime="21" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="131724" startTime="131705" name="huawei_enumerator" duration="20" prePendTime="20" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="148158" startTime="148139" name="SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#Disk+Ven_Generic+Prod_Flash_Disk+Rev_8.07#403BCED0+0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}" duration="18" prePendTime="0" activity="Start" friendlyName="KROTYSOFT_U" description="Flash Disk "/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="146245" startTime="146227" name="srv2" duration="18" prePendTime="18" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130546" startTime="130529" name="USBXHCI" duration="17" prePendTime="17" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="146043" startTime="146026" name="vstor2-mntapi20-shared" duration="17" prePendTime="17" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="131332" startTime="131315" name="klkbdflt" duration="17" prePendTime="17" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="143118" startTime="143102" name="mrxsmb" duration="16" prePendTime="16" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130940" startTime="130925" name="ICCWDT" duration="14" prePendTime="14" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="135993" startTime="135979" name="USB\VID_058F+PID_6387\403BCED0" duration="14" prePendTime="14" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="USB Mass Storage Device"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="132687" startTime="132673" name="USBHUB3" duration="14" prePendTime="14" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130868" startTime="130854" name="RSPCIESTOR" duration="14" prePendTime="14" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="136334" startTime="136321" name="btmhsf" duration="13" prePendTime="13" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="134776" startTime="134763" name="USB\VID_17E9+PID_4301+MI_02\7+36ce9476+0+0002" duration="13" prePendTime="13" activity="Start" friendlyName="USB to Audio" description="USB to Audio"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130568" startTime="130556" name="usbehci" duration="12" prePendTime="12" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="142632" startTime="142620" name="NativeWifiP" duration="12" prePendTime="12" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="145509" startTime="145497" name="PEAUTH" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="148848" startTime="148837" name="RdpVideoMiniport" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="147724" startTime="147713" name="MsLldp" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="131657" startTime="131645" name="SFEP" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="146609" startTime="146598" name="tunnel" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Device" endTime="134218" startTime="134207" name="HDAUDIO\FUNC_01+VEN_8086+DEV_2806+SUBSYS_104D6600+REV_1000\4+3b6b84d4+0+0301" duration="11" prePendTime="0" activity="Start" friendlyName="" description="Intel(R) Display Audio"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="145477" startTime="145467" name="mrxsmb10" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="130463" startTime="130452" name="WinDriver6" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="132140" startTime="132130" name="usbhub" duration="11" prePendTime="11" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="145488" startTime="145478" name="Ndu" duration="10" prePendTime="10" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="145713" startTime="145702" name="srvnet" duration="10" prePendTime="10" activity="Load"/>

<pnpObject type="Driver" endTime="131753" startTime="131743" name="rdpbus" duration="10" prePendTime="10" activity="Load"/>

</phase>

</pnp>
```

Comment: I posted what I saw from the trace.

Answer (score 0):

So in the summary you see that the PreSMSS subphase is slow:

> What Happens in This Subphase The **PreSMSS subphase** begins when the
>   kernel is invoked. During this subphase, the kernel initializes data
>   structures and components. It also starts the **PnP manager, which
>   initializes the BOOT_START drivers that were loaded during the
>   OSLoader phase. When the PnP manager detects a device, it loads and
>   initializes the device’s drivers**
>
> Visual Cues PreSMSS begins approximately when the “Loading Windows”
>   splash screen appears. There are no explicit visual cues for the end
>   of PreSMSS.

In your case it is not a required device that takes too long, it is an driver that doesn't show up in this summary.

When you open the ETL, drag & drop the **CPU usage (Sampled)** to the analyze pane:

[image]

you see that System Process takes a high CPU usage for 130s at the beginning of the boot.

[image]

So you need the analyze the [CPU usage of System process](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557). In your case it shows that a Kaspersky Filter driver (`klbackupdisk.sys`) is involved:

[image]

Try to remove Kaspersky. Next I see BitLocker Drive Encryption Driver (fvevol.sys). If you have encrypted the Drive undo this and look if boot is faster.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I did try to remove Kaspersky KTS19 - and it boots same time. I tried to reinstall to older version KTS18 - same. At this point I am pretty much sure it's something conflicting with bitlocker, but the problem is, that I do not have any drives encrypted, and also I tried to turn off this service with no result, so I am not sure what direction to move next. I`ll post new *.etl later today. Thank you.

Comment: Here is new *.etl file: https://mega.nz/#!pzwCmazQ!V7oqOYNnDcQr8T-dvKqpKG2af5W1B7na5Q-G7QPiJlI  Without Kaspersky. I also tried to disable/put to automatic Bitlocker service, also I tried dism restorehealth and sfc /scannow - everything was good, so fvevol.sys is not corrupted. Also tried to put old version of fvevol.sys into drivers folder, same Boot time. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: hm, still the same. I remember that large fragmentation of hibernation file could cause hangs at boot and fvevol.sys shows up as high CPU usage. This was a known issue in 2014, so maybe the issue was never solved. Disable the hibernation in Windows, reboot and look if this makes boot faster.

Comment: Thanks, but that was already done ( moreover it`s raid stripe of 2 ssd's and performance is pretty decent, even it's old laptop. Any other clues I can look at? checked eventlog just in case anything abnormal - with no result too.

Comment: I also saw this RAID (SCSI\DISK&VEN_INTEL&PROD_RAID_0_VOLUME\4&31AC9113&0&000100). Does the issue also happen without the RAID? 1 SSD is still fast enough

Comment: It`s Vaio svz laptop, it comes with raid, and I never tested it without it.. The hassle of testing single drive is pretty much same as reinstalling OS. Unfortunately I don't have enough time for that right now, but probably next month I'll do it) I need to make full backup first with smth like acronis..  Thanks anyway!

Comment: do you know when this starts to happen? What has changed at this time?

Comment: Unfortunatly, as I use my laptop 24/7 i reboot once a week or fewer. it look like it started near beginning  of 2018, I tried to locate a cause by installed programs list, - for example I removed Acronis true image, and it helped to cut half booting time 300 -> 150s, however I think it's slow loading was caused by the same unknown reason. I can provide list of installed apps during this period of time, however I checked it couple times, and seems like nothing except acronis could cause slower boot. Let me know if this is an option to check. Thanks again!

Comment: look if there is a firmware update for that SSD. is Hibernation/Resume faster? I only use this and only reboot once per month at patchday

Comment: Hibernation/resume is pretty much fast -10-20 seconds - totally bearable. Unfortunately Sony does not provide any raid-SSD firmware updates at all.

Comment: ok, so use hibernation/resume now and only reboot once per patchday each month like I do.