# Windows 10 taking 2 minutes in the Pre Session Init phase

Tags: windows-10, boot

Ever since I switched from Intel to AMD Ryzen, my CPU has been booting over 2 minutes (previously it took 7 seconds).
With the help of Google I discovered this post ([Newish Windows 10 installation taking ~ 20 minutes in the pre session init phase](https://superuser.com/questions/1205024/newish-windows-10-installation-taking-20-minutes-in-the-pre-session-init-phase/1205327#1205327)) and recorded my boot performance. Unfortunately, I do not have the expertise to interpret the results. Therefore, I hope a good soul would come to my rescue.

Here is the .ETL for closer inspection
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SQAOX7hgW1HP89P_l-TCxA-3B3tT0-tE

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing equivalent boots? Are you using Sleep, Hibernation or Fast Startup, rather than a complete reboot, in this comparison?

Comment: I am comparing equivalent boots (shutdown without fast startup). But I have changed the CPU, motherboard, and reinstalled Windows (clean install from USB)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Malwarebytes is taking a lot of CPU, you might try to
uninstall it temporarily.

A bigger problem is the Volume Shadow Copy Driver (volsnap.sys).
This is more of a puzzle, so I suggest:

- [Disable System Restore and re-enable](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/99782-enable-disable-system-restore-windows.html).
- Search the manufacturer's Support website for drivers of your motherboard
  to install. If you need help, let me know the exact models of the motherboard and CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I had a chat with @MagicAndre1981 where they recommended to delete system restore points.
Their exact words "volsnap.sys (Microsoft-Windows-VolumeSnapshot-Driver) causes delay. delete system restore points"

I went to System Properties > System protection...

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUbNY.png)

System Restore was already off for all drives, nonetheless I went into "Configure" for each drive and deleted the restore point. What was most unusual was that my 4TB secondary drive had a 1.15TB space used for a restore point.

After I deleted that, my boot time decreased from 2:15 to 0:15 seconds. (without bios time).

I have now disabled System Restore via the Group Policy.

Even though I might be able to squeeze a few seconds more by uninstalling MalwareBytes, I am happy with the 15 seconds and will not be trying to optimize further.

All credits for this expert investigation and an easy solution go to @MagicAndre1981.

I would also like to thank @harrymc for the time they took to investigate my problem.