# New SSD slow boot ~1m30s to boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, performance

I have an old NP530U4B-S01FR that had HDD. I replaced it by a crucial 500Gb.

Installed new Windows 10 on it, after upgrading all drivers and updates, the boot time takes around 1m30s.

I tried following [@magicandre1981 analysis in this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1205327/167207) but I'm not an expert at WPA.

From what I've seen is that the Boot sessioninit-phase takes 85.67seconds which include the smss.exe but then I'm not sure where to look. I've seen that there was a atikmdag.sys somewhere, I tried to dig after that and found a weird behavior.

After uninstalling the HD 7500M/7600m driver from the device manger and rebooting I have no delay at all.

But then Windows proceed to reinstall this driver again and delay came back.

I tried updating manually the .cat driver for the graphic card, same issue.

When I try to launch the driver from AMD website, it says some DLL error.

Attached the WPA file:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrZ00uM9seq04tIJN-vJpO_cEUBRp6S4

Comment: Please elaborate on "_But then Windows proceed to reinstall this driver again and delay came back._" and did you install drivers before initiating Windows Update or installing other software? Specifically, did you install the CPU drivers _(mainly chipset, but others are thermal, etc.)_ first? Windows Update normally refuses to update GPU drivers on laptops, since laptop OEMs usually customize the generic GPU driver they get from the GPU OEM. You can prevent Windows from installing drivers for that specific hardware via [Group Policy](https://superuser.com/a/1746979/529800)

Comment: Hi @JW0914 i let windows update install all drivers, i did not use any other software to update the drivers. I did not install any chipset or CPU drivers with any software, windows update did all.

Comment: Windows Update won't install CPU drivers _(chipset, thermal, etc.)_ and these _must_ be installed first prior to running Windows update or installing other software, then laptop OEM GPU drivers, and finally run Windows Update. General FYI: Windows will run painfully slowly even with an SSD on that laptop, but would run quite snappily on Linux. [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop) would provide the most Windows-like experience and you can run Windows software via [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) or you could run Windows 10 within a VM from Ubuntu if needing the actual OS for something specific

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ If choosing to stick with Windows, since Chipset drivers weren't installed, a clean install of Windows 10 should be done, then chipset and GPU drivers installed, Group Policy set, then Windows Update _(running it, rebooting, re-checking, rebooting, etc. until no more Windows updates are returned)_, and finally software. The chipset drivers are vital and not having them installed will result in random issues on Windows, just as random issues will occur if they're not installed first prior to other drivers and Windows updates _(I don't know why that is, only that that it occurs)_

Comment: From where should i install the correct chipset? intel website directly?

Comment: No, from the laptop OEM's [support page](https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/model/NP530U4B-S01HK/#downloads)

Comment: Ok, seems the slow boot is solved by disabling "EnableULPS" in the registry, this is comon issue with AMD drivers and windows 10 on old system. The link i solved the issue is from here: https://jv16powertools.com/blog/fix-slow-boot-issues-windows10/ . Thanks everyone !